# Dropping /t/ when is next to a consonant

Tags: pronunciation

I was once reading the phrase *next year*, and I was told I should've pronounced *next year* as /nɛks jɪə/, that is, without the /t/.

Does this work with other phrases? Like *count them*?

Comment: People 'slur' words all the time.. Example: "That was so incredible" ... ends up being pronounced as "That waso incredible". Rarely you'll hear someone pronounce the "s" twice

Comment: Many native speakers wouldn't even bother trying to articulate /t/ after /ɛks/ (it's a bit of a mouthful, and if you "overarticulate" it you'll just sound weird). This isn't the same context as *count them*, where Cockneys and some other UK speakers will habitually replace /t/ with a glottal stop (and *some* Americans will replace it with /d/).

Comment: I do not drop the /t/ sound in "next" when I say the phrase "next year".  That may be common in some regions, I am surprised that anyone would suggest that doing so is any kind of general rule.

Comment: @PellMel That's what my teacher told me and I found it quite strange. (He's not a native speaker, though.)

Comment: @Ustanak Your teacher should not be telling you to do this. This is not how 'standard' i.e. TV English is pronounced in either the US or the UK, it's not how I speak under any circumstances, and it's certainly not a general rule for informal pronunciation.

Comment: @Rhidian That's the problem with non-native teachers, so I wanted to make sure this rule wasn't formal.

Comment: @Ustanak The point is that in spoken English people will drop consonants to _some_ degree, depending on accent, formality and so on. But you would rarely hear somebody pronounce e.g. 'my next boyfriend' the same as 'my ex boyfriend'. There is always some semblance of a consonant at the end.

Comment: @Rhidian, I am a native (U.S.) English speaker of getting close to 50 years.  I *do* pronounce the /t/ in "next year", and this is not strange to me or to the other native speakers around me.  Moreover, I dispute your assertion that, as a rule, dropping that sound is typical of U.S. television usage.

Comment: @PellMel Please read the comment properly before criticising. You will find that I was asserting exactly the opposite, that the /t/ should not be dropped.

Comment: But see [In the natural way of speaking, How to pronounce “next stop”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/57359/in-the-natural-way-of-speaking-how-to-pronounce-next-stop)

Answer (score 1):

In many languages, when joining two words together results in three consonants in a row, it is normal to insert a [schwa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa) /ə/ between the two words. This approach is not routinely used by native english speakers, and doing so makes the speaker sound Italian: "I don't-ə-know".

For native english speakers, the /t/ at the end of next is usually pronounced normally when it is followed by a word beginning with a vowel.

When it is followed by a word beginning with a consonant, it is often omitted in unstressed syllables or replaced by a gluttal stop (a short silence) in stressed syllables. Attempts to enunciate the final /t/ 
usually result in the insertion of a schwa /ə/, albeit a small one.

A comment on a [similar question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/88858/do-you-native-speakers-pronounce-dont-ask-as-do%CA%8An%C3%A6sk) referred to the phrase **Don't ask, Don't tell**: most English speakers will clearly enunciate the first t, and will substitute a gluttal stop for the second t.

Does *y* count as a consonant? Yes it does, sort of, but it's not as difficult as some consonants, so it's possible to pronounce the final /t/ without sounding too Italian.

In short: there is no rule saying that you have to pronounce or to omit the final t, but omitting it is a more authentic way of dealing with a three-consonant run than inserting a schwa.

Answer (score 0):

I am a native speaker of a very general General American and I would never omit the `/t/` in "next year". I don't insert a schwa either. Many people say `/nɛks jɪər/` and I would certainly understand it. However, you should be aware that it's not standard and may sound too casual. Don't worry if you can't pronounce it that way, though; most English speakers wouldn't notice (it's a very minor detail).

"Don't ask, don't tell" has two glottal stops (in "don't") and one strong aspirated t (in "tell"). Omitting some of those also sounds colloquial to me.